# Wireguard key exchange

Tags: wireguard

I'm trying to understand whether [Wireguard's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WireGuard) key re-exchanges are done inside of the existing encrypted tunnel, or if they are done outside of that existing encrypted tunnel.

Comment: have you read the technical paper about how it works that's available on its website?

Comment: @schroeder I certainly did, but unlike the SSH specification (which clearly shows the rekey happens inside the encrypted tunnel) I am unable to determine that information from the wireguard protocol specs.

Answer (score 1):

Wireguard doesn't really have a key "re-exchange" like SSH does. It's just the same handshake over again. Each handshake's key is valid for a certain timeframe (say, 3 minutes). If you go to send a packet and the key has less than, say, a minute of life left, another handshake will be started, so that a new key is ready by the time the old one expires. Peers usually keep track of up to three handshakes at a time: the last successful one, the one before that (because some packets using the old key may arrive late), and the one in progress (if applicable).